# Help mathematical induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove by mathematical induction. I was hoping if someone could give me a hint on how to solve this problem.

$$\frac{1}{1^2}+ \frac {1}{2^2} + ....+ \frac{1}{n^2} < 2 - \frac {1}{n} $$ for all integers $n\geq 2$.

Comment: The inductive hypothesis would look something like "Assume that $1/1^2 + 1/2^2 + \cdots + 1/(n-1)^2 < 2 - 1/(n-1)$." If you add $1/n^2$ to both sides of this inequality, you get what you want on the left-hand side - can you compare the right-hand side to your goal?

Comment: So adding $1/n^2$ would allow me to go through the k+1 process?

Comment: Well, with induction, you get to assume the statement for the $n-1$ case and then you have to prove it for the $n$ case (or, equivalently, assume it for the $n$ case and then prove it for the $n+1$ case). One way to do that is to take the statement for the $n-1$ case and then derive the statement for the $n$ case. Adding $1/n^2$ to both sides is the first step for deriving the $n$ case from the $n-1$ case.

Answer (score 1):

1. check this for $k=2$
2. suppose it is true for $n=k$ i.e. 
   $$\frac{1}{1^2}+ \frac {1}{2^2} + ....+ \frac{1}{k^2} < 2 - \frac {1}{k}$$
3. Prove it for $n=k+1$ using 2

$$ \implies \frac{1}{1^2}+ \frac {1}{2^2} + ....+ \frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2} < 2 - \frac {1}{k}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}
\\ =2 -( \frac {1}{k}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^2})
\\=2 -\frac{k^2+k+1}{k(k+1)^2}
\\ < 2 -\frac{k^2+k}{k(k+1)^2}
\\= 2 -\frac{1}{k+1}$$